# Control boot up services in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, ubuntu-9.10

How can I control what services are run when booting the system ? also I am using kexec and noticed several services are not loaded when I run kexec, how can I control those services as well ?

In other words: how can I control regular boot up services and kexec boot up services ? I know how to use S and K in the RC level but does this include kexec and regular boot up ?

Please advice,

Comment: I think you have to take a look at upstart docs on ubuntu site.

Answer (score 0):

Read the well-written manpage for `update-rc.d`, man section 8.